# Using Microdata in complex web page

Tags: search-engine, microdata

I have an existing website. I have pages on this website that represent products with reviews. I want to use microdata to expose the aggregate reviews on Google. My challenge is each product page is fairly complex. We spent a lot of money getting the design the way we wanted it. While our search results look good now, we're not sure how to add the aggregate review information.

I reviewed the information found [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146645). However, that looks like we would have to change our page design. We don't want to do that. Is there a way to get the aggregate review search engine result without changing our design? Ideally, I would really like to just put something in the .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scope metadata to encapsulate you whole page, so even on the body tag. This way the information can be spread around your whole design and still be part of the same entity.

If your information can't be hierarchical to form the correct entity you can use the [itemref attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#attr-itemref). To quote the standard:

> Note: The itemref attribute is not part of the microdata data model. It is merely a syntactic construct to aid authors in adding annotations to pages where the data to be annotated does not follow a convenient tree structure.

Comment: Than you for your response. Do you know of an online example that shows this. I'm trying to grasp it, but I don't feel I fully understand it.